# Google Analytics Event tracking for download not working

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track downloads on a PDF. "Real time" goals show nothing, and even when I wait and look back a few days later, no clicks appear.

**For GA, I'm using**

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX-1');
</script>
```

**For the download my code is**

```
<a href="Resources.pdf" onClick="ga('send', 'event', 'download', PDF', 'free-freemium-resources', value, {'NonInteraction': 1});"> CLICK HERE  </a>
```

**I've also tried** `<a href="Resources.pdf" onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'download', PDF', 'free-freemium-resources', value, {'NonInteraction': 1});"> CLICK HERE  </a>`

**And here's my event details**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library is `gtag.gs` but you are trying to send an event with two other different libraries (universal and classic), so you have to use this code to send an event to Analytics:

```
gtag('event', <action>, {
  'event_category': <category>,
  'event_label': <label>,
  'value': <value>
});
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/events